# cor() function in R with a subset

Tags: r, for-loop, correlation

I have a table in R with three columns. I want to get the correlation of the first two columns with a subset of the third column following a specific set of conditions (values are all numeric, I want them to be > a certain number). The `cor()` function doesn't seem to have an argument to define such a subset.

I know that I could use the `summary(lm())` function and square-root the r^2, but the issue is that I'm doing this inside a `for` loop and am just appending the correlation to a separate list that I have. I can't really append part of the summary of the regression easily to a list.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
for (i in x) {list[i] = cor(data$column_a, data$column_b, subset = data$column_c > i)}
```

Obviously, though, I can't do that because the cor() function doesn't work with subsets.

(Note: x = seq(1,100) and list = NULL)

Comment: Using a full set of a and b and then using a subset of c doesn't make much sense when you are looking at correlation. Just subset the whole dataset?

Comment: How would I do that inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset the data first, and then find the correlation.

```
a <- subset(airquality, Temp < 80 & Month > 7)
cor(a$Temp, a$Wind)
```

Edit: I don't really know what your `list` variable is, but here is an example of dynamically changing the subset based on `i` (see how the month requirement changes with each iteration)

```
list <- seq(1, 5)

for (i in 1:5){

  a <- subset(airquality, Temp < 80 & Month > i)
  list[i] <- cor(a$Temp, a$Wind)

}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would work, but I can't do it inside a for loop (or at least I don't know how) - and I *do* need a for loop

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a loop using `lapply`. Here's some code that will output a data frame with the month-range in one column and the correlation in another column. The `do.call(rbind...` business is just to take the list output from `lapply` and turn it into a data frame.

```
corrs = do.call(rbind, lapply(min(airquality$Month):max(airquality$Month), 
                              function(x) {
          data.frame(month_range=paste0(x," - ", max(airquality$Month)), 
             correlation = cor(airquality$Temp[airquality$Month >= x & airquality$Temp < 80],
                               airquality$Wind[airquality$Month >= x & airquality$Temp < 80]))
          }))

corrs 
  month_range correlation
1       5 - 9  -0.3519351
2       6 - 9  -0.2778532
3       7 - 9  -0.3291274
4       8 - 9  -0.3395647
5       9 - 9  -0.3823090
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the pseudo-code you provided alone, here's something that should work:

```
for (i in x) {
    df <- subset(data, column_c > i)
    list[i] = cor(df$column_a, df$column_b)
}
```

However, I don't know why you would want your index in `list[i]` to be the same value that you use to subset `column_c`. That could be another source of problems.

Comment: Maybe making the assignment to `list[as.character(i)]`?